# dual boot of linux mint 14 with windows 8

Tags: multi-boot, grub, linux-mint

I have acer 4750G and is running windows 8. I have 3  primary partition and a single unallocated partition where i intended to install linux mint.

The problem that i am facing is the installer hasnot detected the existing operating system and the partitions available. It is just mentioning that the whole drive is free and showing a single partition and asking me to install in that whole partition or not.

how to proceed so that I may not fall in to trouble with grub ?